# mysql query causes page to get corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

crud_model:

```
public function get_latest_courses($all_lang = NULL) {
    $this->db->where('status', 'active');
    if($all_lang == NULL):
        $this->db->where('language', $this->session->userdata('lang'));
-->     $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
    else:
        $this->db->order_by('language','ASC');
    endif;
    $data = $this->db->get('course');
--> if($data){
        return $data;
    }else{
        return $this->db->error();
    }
  }
```

for some reason after adding:

`$this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');`

90% of the time everything is fine, 10% of the time it causes the query to fail and return `error 500`;

i have run this query directly on phpmyadmin:

`` select * from `course` Where `status` = 'active' AND `language` = 'hebrew' order by `id` ASC ``

and it took 0.0005 seconds, that is not really pointing on a slow query operation,

i have added a condition to try and get the mysql error but it looks like after the order_by it exits the
code (that cusses the 500 error display) and never gets to the if statement.

Comment: Check your web servers error log to see what the 500 error actually is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , server error log empty (no error detected)

Comment: Then check your php.ini and make sure `error reporting` is set to `E_ALL`. While debugging, you could also set `display errors` to `On` (unless it's on a public server) to see the actual error message directly on the screen. You need to find the error message, since that will be the clue to what fails. There's nothing in the posted code that should cause it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added both ( reporting & display ) , again error log empty & no error was displayed

Comment: Did you restart the web server (if you're using apache) or php-fpm (if not using apache) after you updated your php.ini? Was it the correct one? You need to figure out how to find the logging in your environment since that will be required.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson restarted apache and still no error displayed/logged